# flask admin: How to make a query according to the current user's id and role?

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin, flask-security

I used the classes below, allowing users to edit their own profile after registering and it works well. I achieve this using `get_query` and `get_count_query`.

However, if the current user is **administrator**, how can I customize it to let him/her view all users' profiles instead of just his/her own profile? Thanks in advance.

```
 from flask_admin.contrib.sqla.view import ModelView, func

 class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   first_name = db.Column(db.String(255))
   last_name = db.Column(db.String(255))
   email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
   password = db.Column(db.String(255))

   def __str__(self):
     return self.email

 class UserView(ModelView):
   """
   Restrict only the current user can see his/her own profile
   """
   def get_query(self):
      return self.session.query(self.model).filter(self.model.id==current_user.id)
   def get_count_query(self):
      return self.session.query(func.count('*')).filter(self.model.id==current_user.id)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define another custom `ModelView` for administrator. For example:

```
class UserViewForAdmin(ModelView):

    def is_accessible(self):
        return current_user.has_role("admin")
    def inaccessible_callback(self, name, **kwargs):
        return redirect(url_for("security.login", next=request.url))

    pass

admin = Admin(name="Flask-Admin Example")

admin.add_view(UserView(User, db.session, name="Profile")
admin.add_view(UserViewForAdmin(User, db.session, name="UserList", endpoint="users")
```

The is example assume you use `Flask-Security` to do user management.

Answer (score 3):

Another option here is to check the user and handle accordingly in y our `get_query` or `get_count_query` such as:

```
def get_query(self):
  if current_user.username == 'admin':
    return self.session.query(self.model)
  else:
    return self.session.query(self.model).filter(
      # your existing filter for user
    )
```

*Note: the above uses `current_user` from flask_security but can be adapted to other logic easily.*